# How to make a string palindrome?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

Create a function which takes a string as parameter. Return the shortest palindrome  formed by adding the letter to that string.

```
"abc" // cbabc
"21234" // 4321234
"321234" // 4321234
"a"      // a
```

What I have tried so far is below.

```js
function isPal(str){
    return [...str].reverse().join('') === str;
}   
function palindrome(s){
    if(isPal(s)) return s;
    for(let i = 0;i<s.length;i++){
        if(isPal(s)) return s;
        s = s.slice(0,i) + s[s.length - 1 - i] + s.slice(i)
    }
    return s;
}

console.log(palindrome('abc'))
console.log(palindrome('321234'))
console.log(palindrome('21234'))
console.log(palindrome('a'))
```

The code works fine but its not efficient because its checking for `isPal` during each iteration.
I would like to know the efficient solution for the problem. I can't calculate the time-complexity of the solution but its clears it not linear. I want to know the solution with linear time-complexity or better than mine.

Comment: The question is quite clear and I have showed my try so what is reason for downvote?

Comment: @Kaiido I edited the question. By performance I meant time-complexity. And time -complexity questions don't need the length of input.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes we have to find the missing string which should be added to start of string to make a string palindrome.

Comment: @MaheerAli - I don't know how to implement it yet, but maybe you could try and detect the larger palindrome within your string, and then append the reversed rest to the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `r = reversed string (s)`

Find the longest **suffix** of `r` equal to **prefix** of `s`  (checking char by char)

```
    a b c 
c b a

for another example
        2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2

but better variant does exist:
    2 1 2 3 4
4 3 2 1 2
```

Note that you really **don't need** to build reversed string - just use corresponding indexes

Both operations should be linear.

---

Edit: Modified code exploiting [z-function](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html)
(thanks @Kalido for pointing to `abcdba` test case)

It is possible to use [z-functio](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/z-function.html)n mentioned in your earlier theme. I am not familiar with JS (enough to properly make result strings), so just made z-array for comparison of string suffix with prefix of reversed one (note index mangling in the right part here `s[z[i]] == s[n - 1 - i - z[i]]`)

Code looks for the largest value `z[maxi]` except for the first item. The first item is used only if it is equal to n (string already is palindrome). Result is length of prefix to add.

For example, `21234` gives `z[maxi]=3`, so function returns 2 (we add prefix of `43212`of length `5-3=2`), ie `43` = > `43 21234`

`cabac` gives `z[0] = 5 = n`, result is zero, so we don't need to add anything

`abcdba` gives `z[0] = 2 < n`,  so we choose maximum among other items

```js
function ex_z_function(s) {
  var n = s.length;
  var z = Array(n).fill(0);
  var i, l, r, maxi = 1;
 
  for (i = 0, l = 0, r = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (i <= r)
      z[i] = Math.min(r - i + 1, z[i - l]);
    while (i + z[i] < n && s[z[i]] == s[n - 1 - i - z[i]])
      ++z[i];
    
   if ((i > 0) && (z[i] > z[maxi]))
      maxi = i;

    if (i + z[i] - 1 > r)
      l = i, r = i + z[i] - 1;
  }
  if (z[0] == n) {
     return 0;
  }
  return n - z[maxi];
}

console.log(ex_z_function("a"));
console.log(ex_z_function("abc"));
console.log(ex_z_function("abac"));
console.log(ex_z_function("cabac"));
console.log(ex_z_function("21234"));
console.log(ex_z_function("abcdba"));
console.log(ex_z_function("abacaba"));
console.log(ex_z_function("vfvcabgvcvfv"));
```

Comment: @MaheerAli, did you try to write it yourself based on these instructions?

Comment: @trincot Yes. But I am confused with the reverse string part. I want to know should i convert it to array or use `slice()` because we can't modify strings.

Comment: Well, it is the same as you already do in the `isPal` function. `let r = [...str].reverse().join('');`

Comment: @MBo Thanks for answer. The first approach is nice. TBH i don't like z-function its very complicated.

Comment: It is the same approach - using z-function is just a method to compare suffixes/prefixes effectively (yes, I realize that in JS usage of in-built functions for copying  string parts and their comparison might be faster)

Comment: Somehow fails with inputs like `abcdba` (returns `4` instead of `5`), not quite sure why, but it seems the pattern is at least two characters mirrored at extremities which do surround some non mirrored content.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh, my mistake in z-function implementation (accidentally I started loop here from 0 while `i=1` needed), but I fitted interpretation to erroneous code :-), it should be changed.

Comment: @Kaiido I recalled that I made `i=0` intentionally, but seems that cell z[0] should be used only if string is palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

You could already gain a lot of time on your `isPal` function by just checking half the string, or return if the check fails early:

```js
function isPal(str){
    for (let i = 0, l = str.length; i < l / 2; i++) {
      if (str[i] != str[l-i-1]) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
} 

console.log(isPal('kayak'))
console.log(isPal('toot'))
console.log(isPal('john'))
```

https://jsperf.com/palindrome-detection

*Note*: the complexity of `isPal` remains linear but the best case is far better.

Comment: The point is to remove the `isPal` check every time and I knew that half string algorithm. But I didn't added it to confuse the viewers to check what is going of in `isPal`. But thanks and +1. The time complexity of `isPal` becomes `O(n/2)` not linear.

Comment: O(n/2) is still O(n)

Comment: @trincot indeed, the idea, however, is here that best case is o(1).